# Cumulative count of repeated values, starting at 1

Tags: sql, count, aginity

I have a list of individual ID keys that have duplicates.  I'd like to deduplicate this by counting the instance of each repeated key.  I can count the cumulative total, or count the number of repeated instances, but not count incrementally from 1 through x at the next first instance of the ID key.

Example, this is what I'd like to achieve
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc9Jd.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Query

```
Select IndividualKey,Row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY IndividualKey ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))ID From Table
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you